# API response with a proxy is working with the curl, but nothing is returned with python

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, proxy-server

I am trying to access data using API which is behind the proxy server. If I use `curl` command like below it works:

```
curl --proxy http://MY_PROXY_SERVER:PORT --header "Accept: application/csv" http://WEB_SERVER_ADDRESS/data/CHANNEL?start=1470011400
```

I get the data which is expected.

When I am trying to access the same URL with python either by `requests` or `urllib2` I am not able to get the data back. This is the code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import requests

s = requests.Session()
s.proxies = {"http": "http://MY_PROXY_SERVER:PORT"}

headers = {'Accept': 'application/csv'}
url = "http://WEB_SERVER_ADDRESS/data/CHANNEL?start=1470011400"

r = s.get(url, headers=headers)
print(r.text)
```

I don't get any error and request is able to go through the python successfully. The output is empty list. I also tried with other media type supported by API like 'json', issue still persists.